# how to make the bar long as much as the main windows

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

### I wrote this piece code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

app = Tk()
app.title('Myapp')
app.geometry('200x150+50+50')

labelText =StringVar()
labelText.set('Insert the version you want to check')
label1 = Label(app, textvar=labelText, height=2)
label1.pack()

stringadacercare = StringVar(None)
lastringa = Entry(app, textvar=stringadacercare)
lastringa.pack(side='left',padx=5,pady=30)

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack(side="bottom")
progressbar.start()

app.mainloop()
```

---

The result is this:

[image: screen shot]

What I've been trying to do was the progress bar long as much as the main windows, however
it doesn't work with the textbox.

How can make it work? Is there another way to create a text box that is also easier to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pack` you can request that a widget expands in either axis. For example:

```
progressbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid geometry manager is possibly easier for a beginner http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm  You can use row and column to place the widgets.  If you place the progress bar in a separate row, you can then adjust the length to get what I think you want.